# Get providerData from Firebase User

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add the unlink provider function in my app. I want to add a button that unlinks a user's Facebook account from their Firebase user account. The Firebase documentation says to use the providerData array, but I don't know how to extract the Facebook provider ID from it. If I just use `let providerID = self.currentUser.providerID`, it just defaults to the first provider in the array, regardless of what the type is (Facebook, Twitter, Firebase, etc..).

How can I extract the Facebook provider ID from providerData? This is how I tried to get it but it errors ("cannot subscript a value of type [String] with an index type of String"):

```
guard let providerData = self.currentUser?.providerData else {return}
        var providerArray: [String] = []
        for provider in providerData{
            providerArray.append(provider as! String)
        }
        var providerID: String = providerArray["Facebook"]
        FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.unlink(fromProvider: providerID) { (user, error) in
```

EDIT:

Fixed by using

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.unlink(fromProvider: "facebook.com" ) { (user, error) in
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `providerArray` like a Dictionary and that will not work. What you are looking for is the providerId specifically for Facebook. In order to retrieve this, you need to get the FIRAuthCredential for Facebook. In order to do this you should use [FIRFacebookAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuthCredential). This will get you the credential, from the credential you can grab the providerId, match it to the current user's array of providerIds like you are doing. Then unlink as you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually just solved this by passing in "facebook.com" as the providerID. I only show the unlink button if a Facebook auth token is present

Comment: That's fine. I would just probably not use a string like that considering if they change that value in the API then your code wouldn't work :/ Just a suggestion!

Comment: @james I would use the logic I posted above to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by only showing the unlink button if a Facebook auth token is present. Then, when the button is pressed, just pass in "facebook.com" as the providerID:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.unlink(fromProvider: "facebook.com" ) { (user, error) in
```